# Redirect with htaccess from index.php to another.php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I want to create pretty url. But, I got some problem with .htaccess. For example I have url **domain/some.php?f=query-string**.
I want to change **domain/query-string** (expected url). Is that possible to change / redirect via .htaccess. Or maybe from php file itsself.

this is a bit of htaccess snippet i made, but i get it blank/error page

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/([^/.]+)$ some.php?f=$1    [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/([^/.]+)$ some.php?f=$1    [NC,L]
> ```

In `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash, so the above will never match and it will do nothing. This should be written like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ some.php?f=$1 [L]
```

The `NC` flag is not required here, since the regex is already "case-insensitive".

Comment: Thanks for your explain. But, I try your answer above and still getting error (content in the some.php not showing up).

Comment: @djodev What is the actual URL you are requesting? What is the precise "error" you are getting? What is in `some.php`?

Comment: To be honest, everything went well because of your answer above. Thanks @MrWhite  :) To be honest, everything went well because of your answer above. Thank you. After I looked at my php file again, it turned out that there was an error in the if else statement.